# Within emacs, how do I reference the physical screens?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I have a multi-screen display.  Within emacs (GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) on Windows 7), how can I determine the number of physical screens, and cause things to happen on different screens?  For example, I might want to open a new frame in a different screen, or I might want to move the frame in which Emacs is starting to another screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if these functions work on Windows, but on Linux and Mac OS X you can use:

- `x-display-screens`: Number of monitors
- `x-display-pixel-width`: Current screen (screen that contains Emacs windows) width
- `x-display-pixel-height`: Current screen height
- `set-frame-width` and `set-frame-height`: resize
- `set-frame-position`: Move frame

For example if you want to create a new frame in another screen, you can do:

```
(when (and (display-graphic-p) (= (display-screens) 2))
  (make-frame)
  (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 1280 0))
```

Where 1280 is the width of your first screen.

Comment: You can also take a look at my setup https://github.com/tungd/dotfiles/blob/master/emacs/init.el#L278

Comment: It looks like x-display-screens doesn't work on my Emacs implementation on Windows.  It returns "1 (#o1, #x1)", and I have three screens.  Display-screens returns the same thing.

Comment: What about `x-display-pixel-width`? If it returns something like the total width of your screens then that would still be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, x-display-pixel-width appears to just provide the width of the current screen for Windows.

Comment: Have you tried the official binary over here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/. If that still not working then you might have to wait for 24.4 when native support for this is added (`frame-monitor-attributes` and `display-monitor-attributes-list`)

Comment: I haven't yet.  Thanks for providing me a giggle.  When I looked at that site, I read, "Unfortunately, on Windows 95 and 98, ..."  It looks like they need to update their site even more than I need to update my Emacs.

Comment: My Emacs does seem to have some awareness of the Windows screens.  posn-at-x-y returns "(#<window 3 on .emacs> ..."  However, the describe-function on it says "posn-at-x-y is a built-in function in `C source code'", so I don't yet see how I can leverage that to get at the available screens.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout pos-tip.el code (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/pos-tip.el)

It says it works in X and Windows so probably you could find some compatible layer in it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but it looks to me that it is using x-display-pixel-width and friends to do screen calculations.  I didn't see anything that looked like it was cognizant of Windows screens.

Comment: Did you try using it?  Why not install and use it first to see if it works?